# Distance Matrix analysis for QGIS 2.8 using one layer

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix, proximity

I'm using QGIS 2.8's Distance Matrix tool to find distances to nearest neighboring points on a single layer. I've followed roughly the instructions on this [site](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html) and adapted it to my needs. However, I'm having issues with the resulting data. In my example, I've used myLayer as both input and target layers to find the three nearest points. I then added the resulting CSV to QGIS and selected all elements whose InputID = TargetID in order to find the points who were matched with themselves. The strange this, is these distances are not 0.

I get this sort of result:

```
InputID TargetID Distance
PointA   PointA   23.023
PointB   PointB   4.532
```

Can someone please explain to me where this distance comes from? My ultimate goal is to find the distance for each point to it's two nearest neighbors (not including itself).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to explain your results without seeing your dataset.  You may have a problem with your attribute data (non-unique InputID / TargetID?).

I tested *Distance Matrix* in QGIS 2.8.2 using a Shapefile format layer with a projected CRS.

Only neighbour points with a distance greater than 0 to the "reference point" were included in the output CSV file.

So if you use the same layer for both input and output, you should get the two closest neighbours by using the "Linear (N*k x 3)" output type with k=3.  The neighbour points with distance 0 are not reported, but they seem to be "counted", so with k=3 you will get the two nearest points.